# Syntax error with wexpect

Tags: python

I did download the latest copy of `wexpect` from github and placed it in the site-packages folder of my working directory for python.
I also installed the py32 packages as instructed.
When I try to run the `import wexpect` command from IDLE I get the following error message

```
import wexpect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\wexpect.py", line 94
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could you please give me some pointers as to how to debug.

Comment: It looks like you're using a Python2 version of the package with Python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the app using Python 3, while the syntax `except ImportError, e:` is for Python 2. In Python 3, it's `except ImportError as e:`.

If it's a library code, either search for the latest version of the library for Python 3, or run it using Python 2 otherwise.